# Why does Twitter pass strings into it's script loading JS snippet?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Below is the Twitter script loading snippet you use to add a Tweet button to a webpage.

```
!function(d,s,id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];

  if (!d.getElementById(id)){ 
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
  }
}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
```

On the last line, they pass `"script"` into the IIFE arguments, rather than just declaring it as a variable.

What is the benefit of doing this? Is it just to save a couple of characters on the code length?

Comment: actually both options are eqal in character length. they saved one '=' and one ',' but introduced two ','. also if they were trying to save bytes, they would've ditched the `var` declaration altogether and used one-char variable names. im interested in an answer, too, but i guess its just someone's personal coding style?

Comment: Facebook also do it in their [like button generator](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/). That would point to it being more than just personal coding style (unless one copied the other I suppose).

Comment: maybe separating string vars from object vars?

Answer (score -2):

If they used a variable outside the IIFE, it might interfere with the variables in 10,000 peoples' javascript on 10,000 peoples' web pages. If there was already a variable by that name their inclusion on the page might interfere with the way it worked and people would say, "I tried to use Twitter, but it broke my web page." Whether true or not.

Doing it the way they did leaves as little impact on the surrounding code as possible.

**A variable inside**

If they put a variable on the inside it would be harder to document what has to be added to an already working web page. They would have to teach a newby javascript user how to format string variables and the new guys would have to enter their information in two places in the code.

This way they only have to show all the lines but the last one as "magic". "Copy these lines in", they say.

Then they explain you have to put the names of two things in the quotes on the last line. Its just easier to explain.

Admittedly, its not a lot easier. But a little easier to explain times thousands of people using it could increase their market penetration, so to speak.

Comment: But does the immediately-invoked function wrapping the code not localise any variables they declare? That would prevent them interfering with other JS code on the page.

Comment: Oh, I thought you meant a variable on the outside of the function.